# VBA: Conditional Formatting Based of Two Criteria w/ Ref to Offset Cells

Tags: excel, vba, offset, conditional-formatting, multiple-conditions

**RESOLVED**

> Answer: In conditional formatting rules "$" needed to be removed.

**Story:**

So I got it working with Conditional Formatting rules.

I'm using

`=AND(F1=10,G1="D")` applied to the cell `E1` (it will be a certain colour)

*This is in conditional formatting rules*

G column has a value of either C or D

F column has value from 1-10

E column will be effected

Trying to do this condition formatting in VBA

**Option 1:**

So my VBA idea will look like...

```
if the offset right cell 2 over = "D" it's TRUE
~~~then run~~~
///Because if Column G doesn't have a D then nothing happens
///Second condition that comes after

if the offset right cell 1 over = "1"
~~~then~~
=condtional formatting "red"

if the offset right cell 1 over = "2"
~~~then~~
=condtional formatting "blue"

if the offset right cell 1 over = "3"
~~~then~~
=condtional formatting "green"

*this goes all the way from 1-10*
```

**Option 2:**

Is there way to copy the conditional formatting **code** easily

When I copy down the effected cell changes but not the code.

EXAMPLE:

`=AND(F1=10,G1="D")` then `E1` will be a certain colour

*copy it to row 2*

`=AND(F1=10,G1="D")` then `E2` will be a certain colour

I have been manually changing the code to

`=AND(F2=10,G2="D")` then `E2` will be a certain colour

It has become very tedious doing in down 250 rows.

**In response to paste special format:**

[Column G are all labelled D and column F has various numbers. Column E font changes depending on the number and only if column G have the letter D. Row 25, Column E is suppose to be dark green][1]

[After pasting special format. Row 25, Column E turned light green because Row 24 has D = true and 9 in Column F. I go and look at the rule, The rule `=AND($F$24=10,$G$1+$F$24="D")` stayed the same and did not automatically changed to `=AND($F$25=10,$G$1+$F$25="D")` *(like I've been trying to accomplish)* but the applied cell however did changed to $E$25 *(which is as well wanted)*. So the conditions are being determined by the row above not the row that cell is suppose to be affected.][2]

[I have been manually going into rules manager and changing the code for every single colour so I have been manually changing `=AND($F$24=10,$G$1+$F$24="D")`  to `=AND($F$25=10,$G$1+$F$25="D")`for every single colour. As you can see I get the result of Column E row 23 being dark green][3]

I'm trying to find an alternative to this method because it needs to be applied to 250 rows.

~~IMAGES~~
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/WJnLM.png
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kf4S9.png
[3]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/cPI7d.png

Comment: If you select the whole block in ColE which you want to add CF to (select from the top down, so E1 is the "active cell") , and enter the formula for the first row as you show, it will adjust automatically for the rest of the cells.   PS  - G, F and E are *columns* not rows: it's easier to follow your question if you use the regular terms people are used to seeing when talking about ranges.

Comment: I think you miss understood. When I did as you asked and still left with the same problem all other cells follow the first cells conditions.

when i copy it down I want the code to change from


=AND(F1=10,G1="D") then E1 will be a certain colour

=AND(F2=10,G2="D") then E2 will be a certain colour

Comment: If you apply the rules to E1 and then fill down it should work - it will not *seem* like it's correct if you look at the formula, but if you check the *functionality* it should be correct.  If you want to copy the CF to another cell then copy>>pastespecial/formats should also work.

Comment: I updated as a response for it didn't work

Comment: If you want your CF formula to adjust to other cells as you fill down or copy/pastespecial then it should contain no `$` - if you include the `$` then the formula is "locked" to that reference, same as a regular cell formula.  See https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/blog/2012/02/27/conditional-formatting-rules-simplified/#:~:text=To%20do%20this%2C%20select%20the,absolute%20reference%20(%24B%242) and https://www.ablebits.com/office-addins-blog/2014/08/07/relative-absolute-cell-references-excel-conditional-formatting/ for example

Comment: Thank you Tim. I removed the $ and it worked.